# Get by tag and add label

Tags: jquery

I'm currently working on Wordpress and i have this html code :

```
<div class="single-price-wrapper">
     <p class="price">
        <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">989.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">лв.</span></span></del> 
        <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">239.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">лв.</span></span></ins>
     </p>
</div>
```

i can not add or edit class names or ids on the rows. How to catch price in  tag and before price to add label like "Price" and catch price in  tag and before this price to append label "Real price"?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Is it possible you could show the HTML structure you want to create after the JS has been run, and also your own attempts at solving this problem.

Comment: check woocommerce for any available hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a javascript / jQuery solution:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // I guess you have many products or whatever it is
  $('p.price').each((i, e) => {
    // .before(...) is OK too.
    $(e).find('del').wrap(
      $('<label>').text('Price: ')
    );
    
    $(e).find('ins').wrap(
      $('<label>').text('Real price: ')
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="single-price-wrapper">
     <p class="price">
        <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">989.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">лв.</span></span></del> 
        <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">239.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">лв.</span></span></ins>
     </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS rule using before with content

```css
.price > * > span:before {
  content: "Price "
}
```

```html
<div class="single-price-wrapper">
     <p class="price">
        <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">989.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">лв.</span></span></del> 
        <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">239.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">лв.</span></span></ins>
     </p>
</div>
```

If you want to inject it with JavaScript

```js
$(".price > * > span").before("<label>Price: </label>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-price-wrapper">
     <p class="price">
        <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">989.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">лв.</span></span></del> 
        <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">239.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">лв.</span></span></ins>
     </p>
</div>
```